Flutter Download Background Isolate to update UI thread didn't work
I want to implement flutter_download v1.11.0 into my flutter project. I use GetX as state management and put my download operation inside GetxController. but some how the callback didn't progressing update.
This is my controller's code
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        _port.sendPort, 'downloader_send_port');
    _port.listen((dynamic data) {
      final status = DownloadTaskStatus.fromInt(data[1] as int);
      progress.value = data[2] as int;
      print("progress ${progress.value}");
      if (status == DownloadTaskStatus.complete) {
        FlutterDownloader.open(taskId: data[0]);
      }
    });

    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
  }

Future<void> download(String link) async {

    taskId.value = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
      url: link,
      headers: {},
      // optional: header send with url (auth token etc)
      savedDir: localDir.value,
      showNotification: true,
      saveInPublicStorage: true,
      // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
      openFileFromNotification:
          true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
    );
 
}

@override
void dispose() {
  IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
  super.dispose();
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
static void downloadCallback(String id, int status, int progress) {
  final SendPort? send =
      IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port');
  print("callback ${progress}");
  send?.send([id, status, progress]);
}

I have refer to this issue page https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/804 , but I still didn't get it how that affect the process. Is it because I implement on GetxController instead of Statefull Widget or there is issue in my code?
